# protected stream operator in an abstract class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, abstract-class, protected

I have seen a few examples of abstract classes with a friend `operator<<` and a virtual "`print`" member function where the two declarations are both in the `protected` section. For example:

```
class Function{
public:
    virtual ~Function() {} 
    virtual double value(const double x) const = 0;
    virtual Function* clone() const = 0;
protected:
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Function& f);
    virtual void print(ostream& os) const = 0;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Function& f){
    f.print(os);
    return os;
}
```

I do not understand why this is mandatory. Can someone explain?

Thanks!

Comment: Why *what* is mandatory?

Comment: Please learn to write **declaration** correctly... Didn't you notice that [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907019/friend-declaration-in-protected-section) was edited? (link: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17907019/revisions) Reading "decleration" makes me sad :'(

Comment: Ok I fixed it myself... Now there's still `operator<<`'s parameter `Function& f` that should be `const Function& f` (twice), since printing `f` should _not_ modify it, but I didn't want to touch the code (actually I've just noticed that I added a missing `;` after the class definition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it doesn't matter where you declare the `friend` function/operator. It isn't `public`, `protected` or `private`. It is just a `friend` function/operator, so it has access to the class' members, not matter their access restrictions. So the stream operator **is not protected**. It is a `friend`, and this allows it to access the `print()` method.

Second, the `print` method should probably be `private`. It would only make sense for it to be `protected` if you want to call the `print` method of a base class from a more derived one. But the design suggests that it is an implementation detail in order to implement `ostream& operator<<`.

If, on the other hand, you designed your class such that it made sense for the `print` method to be public, there would be no need for the `ostream& operator<<` to be a `friend`.

Comment: Why should the `print` function be private?  Since it is `const`, it can't invalidate any invariants, it has no preconditions, and no post conditions that you could possibly verify.  It is, practically, accessible from the public interface via `<<`.  I can't think of any possible reason not to make it `public`.

Comment: @JamesKanze I see it as a means to implement the output stream operator `<<`. As such, I saw no need for it in the public interface of the class.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly not mandatory.  In fact, I would argue that it is
poor design.

Where you put the friend declaration has no importance; access
spedifiers don't apply to it.  Since the `operator<<` *is* part
of the public interface, regardless of where you declare it, it
makes more sense to declare it in the public area of the class,
since that's where users who aren't deriving from the class will
look for it.

With regards to the `print` function, I can also so no real
reason for declaring it anything but public.  Given that most,
if not all accesses to it will be via the friend `operator<<`,
it probably doesn't matter, but I don't see what is gained by
declaring it `private`.  And as a general rule, *nothing* is
gained by declaring anything `protected`; it's very rare to use
`protected`.  In the mid 1990s, it was argued that you should
declare virtaul functions `protected`, rather than `public`, and
parts of the standard library still reflect this convention.
But I think that the consensus today is that 1) if this rule
applies, the virtual functions should be `private`, not
`protected`, and 2) this rule doesn't always apply—in the
case of a const function, like `print`, it practically never
applies.